# How to use escape sequences in configuration files in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-16.04, http-proxy, regex

I had a problem of tunneling apt from a http proxy in Ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy

https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal

These questions describe the problem and solution.
It requires I create a file 'apt.conf' file and enter a line in the following format.

```
http://[username]:[password]@[proxy-webaddress]:[port]
```

The problem is the password has '@' in it.

This is the error I get.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tBT3.jpg)

The question is how do I include password in the configuration files.

I tried using "@" and "/@" both gave errors, not exactly the same but similar in terms of "Temporary failure in resolving the ID and Password"

This is what I wrote

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://tarun:usa@9356@192.17.2.4:808/";
```

I have tried,

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://tarun:usa\'@\'9356@192.17.2.4:808/";

Acquire::http::proxy "http://tarun:usa\@9356@192.17.2.4:808/";

Acquire::http::proxy "http://tarun:usa/@9356@192.17.2.4:808/";

Acquire::http::proxy "'http://tarun:usa/@9356@192.17.2.4:808/'";

Acquire::http::proxy "\'http://tarun:usa/@9356@192.17.2.4:808/\'";

Acquire::http::proxy "`http://tarun:usa/@9356@192.17.2.4:808/`";
```

Comment: Of course you can also consider changing the password :)

Comment: I would, if I could. But, I do not have the privilages for changing the password. It's a proxy provided to me by my university. They wouldn't change password just for me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. you need to escape **the entire string** not just the @ charcter.
`Acquire::http::proxy "'tarun:usa@9356@http://192.17.2.4:808/'";` - use single quotes inside double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that the error said, `"Could not resolve <address>"`, which implies that `<address>` is a URL. Searching for URL lead me to URL Encodings of characters.

To include `@` in my address, I can encode it using `%40`. Hence, the entire string becomes `http://tarun:usa%409356@192.17.2.4:808`.When parsed %40 is decoded as @. Which worked perfectly.

Here is a link for more 
[URL Encodings](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html

Thanks for the edit. you need to escape **the entire string** not just the **@** charcter. `Acquire::http::proxy "'tarun:usa@9356@http://192.17.2.4:808/'";` - use single quotes inside double quotes

Comment: That post says that to use some special characters, I have use escape sequences. It doesn't have how not to allow the string to ignore first @ and include it in password.

Comment: As, I have said in the post, I have used "\@" and "/@". None of them worked.

Comment: Per the link: "Most characters are ... taken literally by means of placing them in double quotes ("")." Your OP says " '\@' and '/@ ' " but this comment says " "\@" and "/@" " - these are two different things. Linux syntax uses backslashes.

Comment: Post the entire string you are trying to parse (without the password, obviously)

Comment: In the above string. I want the first @ to be included in the password.

Comment: The limit does make sense. Link-only answers are very bad form, and are _strongly_ discouraged. SE sites are meant as archives, and links can go bad over time. You are supposed to add the relevant content in your answer, and still post the link for proper attribution.

Comment: The apt seems to think that proxy address is "9356@http://" and said couldn't resolve it.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: OK that makes sense. Still, some things can be answered in <30 characters.

Comment: After trying out the edited solution. The errors persists saying that 'usa@9356@http' can't be resolved.

Comment: Hm...It shouldn't be parsing the colon, but that's what seems to be breaking it. Few more things to try: First, escape the colon (\:) if that doesn't work, remove it, Then try double-single quotes. (''...'') and if that fails, try escaped double quotes inside single quotes ('\"...\"')